# Loop on ArrayNode tranform to stream

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to use streams() to convert this code. I'm using jackson library.

```
  JsonNode convert(final ObjectNode src) {}
  boolean checkNotEmpty(final JsonNode node) {}


  ArrayNode newArray = mapper.createArrayNode();
  for (final JsonNode node: arrayNodes) {
    JsonNode newNode = convert((ObjectNode) fiwareNode);
    if (checkNotEmpty(newNode)) {
      newArray.add(newNode);
    }
  }
```

Currently I have:

```
 ArrayNode a = StreamSupport.stream(nodes.spliterator(), true)
    .map(e -> convert((ObjectNode)e))
    .filter(e -> checkNotEmpty(e))
    .collect(Collector.of(
          mapper.createArrayNode(), // init accumulator
          ArrayNode::add, // processing each element
      ));
```

However I'm getting:

```
The type ArrayNode does not defined add(R,T) that is applicable here
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Edit:

I found [this](http://whitfin.io/collecting-a-java-8-stream-into-a-jackson-arraynode/). Do I have to implement this class? Is it possible to do it inline? So I guess this is going to be the solution ;)

Comment: Your code is not complete. `Collector.of` accepts at least three elements.

Comment: Thanks.. I realized that I didn't post the full code :( I think the answer is the link I included.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* of course create a new `Collector`. The one in the link you found just does what you want it to do. This is especially useful when you need this piece multiple times.

But if you want to just write a single statement — one of the overloaded versions of the `collect` method in the `Stream` class accepts a supplier, an accumulator and a combiner. The `ObjectMapper` class can create an `ArrayNode` instance through the `createArrayNode` method, while the `ArrayNode` class provides `add` and `addAll` methods. These are all you need:

```
ArrayNode newArray = arrayNodes.stream()
    .map(t -> convert((ObjectNode) t))
    .filter(YourClass::checkNotEmpty)
    .collect(mapper::createArrayNode, ArrayNode::add, ArrayNode::addAll);
```